# Angular - Displaying a font awesome spinner center not working

Tags: sass, font-awesome, angular11

I am trying to display a font awesome spinner horizontally center. With the below CSS it is displaying only on the left hand side. Can anyone help me how to fix this?

*loading.component.html*

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="loading-overlay">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-4x"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

*loading.component.scss*

```css
.loading-overlay {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;    
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `position: absolute;` and you are fine.

```css
.loading-overlay {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="loading-overlay">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-4x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```